# NameError: name 'n' not defined parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have suddenly been getting the `NameError` when I run the python code snippet posted below. I have similar functions defined which is basically web scraping using BS4, but the current function mentioned below throws this error.

I have researched on this error on SO, and have accordingly added the global definitions as well, but still no luck with resolving this. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Python code snippet:

```
def bcnews(self):
    global n, l
    bcheadline = requests.get("https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(bcheadline.content, 'html.parser')
    for data in soup.find_all('div', class_="bc_banner_item cz-banner-item"):
        for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="bc_banner_caption"):
            n = (item.find('h4').contents[0])
            break
        for links in item.find_all('a'):
            l = (links.get('href'))
            break
        break
    return (n,l)
```

Comment: This is a BeautifulSoup issue, nothing specific to Flask. `n` is never set when `soup.find_all()` doesn't find any matches.

Comment: Also, why are you looping over `find_all` when you only wanted the first match?

Comment: `n = soup.select_one('div.bc_banner_item div.bc_banner_caption h4').get_text()` and `l = soup.select_one('div.bc_banner_item a[href]').get('href')` would be more efficient and readable, no loops required. Do catch the `AttributeError` exception those might throw if the specific divs are not present.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! It was indeed a BS4 extraction issue, it is fixed and running :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the `n = ...` assignment never being reached. This would happen if the `for` loop doesn't have anything to iterate over:

```
>>> for i in []:  # empty list
...     n = i
...
>>> n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

The `for` loop has nothing to iterate over if your `soup.find_all()` method calls return an empty result.

The common solution is to make sure *something* is assigned to the name, like `None`:

```
>>> n = None
>>> for i in []:  # empty list
...     n = i
...
>>> n is None  # nothing else was assigned
True
```

However, in your case you don't really need to loop *at all*. You could instead search with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find the *first match* for a nested selector:

```
try:
    title = soup.select_one('div.bc_banner_item div.bc_banner_caption h4').get_text()
    link = soup.select_one('div.bc_banner_item a[href]').get('href')
    return title, link
except AttributeError:
    return None, None
```

Catching `AttributeError` exception takes care of the case where there is no matching element at all (so the `.get_text` or `.get` attribute lookups would fail).